# How to rename properties in objects that are in an array. What is the right way to solve the task?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I need to build diagram, 
There is an array with objects for chart data

```
"graphicDetails": [
          {
            "hour": 0,
            "businessOperationPlansTotalDemand": 8.201753196882908,
            "employeesCount": 0,
            "businessOperationPlans": [
              {
                "name": "operation0",
                "value": 5.999355066255491
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            "hour": 1,
            "businessOperationPlansTotalDemand": 7.450044665662842,
            "employeesCount": 3,
            "businessOperationPlans": []
          },
          {
            "hour": 2,
            "businessOperationPlansTotalDemand": 5.814536267254451,
            "employeesCount": 5,
            ....
```

To draw it in the chart library (chartjs) I need the object to be with the fields `{x: hour, y: businessOperationPlansTotalDemand, etc.}`. Example:

```
data: [
    { x: 0, y: 5.815634, businessOperationPlans: [{operation: ...}] ,
    { x: 1, y: 2.23232, businessOperationPlans: [{operation2: ...}] ,
    ...
]
```

I know i can use forEach or something like this to rename properties, but what is the right way to resolve this task? maybe i should ask backend to make data in other format?

Maybe I need to create a new array based on this with other properties and put it in the computed field in Vue? How can i do this?

Comment: If you need recommendation then - I will say ask BE to give you proper format, Its never the good idea to control data flow modules at FE.

Comment: You can edit the json, using Ctrl+H in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const graphicDetails =  [{
    "hour": 0,
    "businessOperationPlansTotalDemand": 8.201753196882908,
    "employeesCount": 0,
    "businessOperationPlans": [{
      "name": "operation0",
      "value": 5.999355066255491
    }, ]
  },
  {
    "hour": 1,
    "businessOperationPlansTotalDemand": 7.450044665662842,
    "employeesCount": 3,
    "businessOperationPlans": []
  }
];

const newData = graphicDetails.map(a=>{
return {x:a.hour,y:a.businessOperationPlansTotalDemand,businessOperationPlans:a.businessOperationPlans };
})

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array and design as per your new array structure . If you are using any backend , create the structure from there and process the same in computed , rather put it in mounted so it will load the same in the component gets mounted . Best way will be to process the data-set from backend .